# cannot connect to a specific Wi-Fi (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)

Tags: networking, wireless, usb-modem, router, modem

I previously bought a modem router and then I could connect to it via wifi, but for some time now I can't connect to it, every time I try to connect to the modem router it just says "Wi-Fi connecting" but never connects.

I don't have this problem with any of the other modem routers or mobile hotspots.

Besides Ubuntu, I also have a Windows 10 (dual boot) which has no problem connecting to this modem router or other wifis.

**I've tried these methods but they didn't work:**

1. `reboot`
2. `sudo macchanger -a wlxd03745b5590f && reboot`
3. forget the wifi and trying to connect it again
4. unplug and plug the wifi card

Answer (score 1):

You could try nmcli and see what output you get:

```
nmcli d wifi connect "My-SSID" password My-Password
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Only one network didn't work. I was able to connect to different networks and to the network on dual booted WIndows.

Manual settings helped me:

- Check other device with Ubuntu (easiest way to get all the information, but any other device could be used) to get network address, mask, gateway and DNS server address.
- Open Ubuntu WiFi settings and go to IPv4 tab.
- Select manual.
- Enter some network address that isn't allocated (I used some larger one than noted on the other device - change the last number to something between 2 - 254), mask, gateway.
- Enter DNS address below.
- Leave Routes as automatic.
- Turn off/on WiFi.

The problem may be that the address is static, so there can be some conflicts with other devices.